# Why does the total sum of applied tags mismatch?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

On [my page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632019/eugen-konkov) I get a total count of [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tags: **64**, but I just asked 37 and answered 25. This is **62.**

[image: Screen shot showing pop up with detailed information]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gave two [*community wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/294055) answers on the same [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) question as you can see from [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4632019+%5Bgit%5D+wiki%3Ayes). As you can see from the yellow box in your question, it only lists non-wiki answers.

FYI, the question was not initially a wiki question, but you can see from the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/927358/timeline) that it was made a wiki question on Mar 16 '13 at 10:08. You posted your answers afterwards. But this doesn't matter, because if a question is made a community wiki, then all answers become wiki posts as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is already mentioned that:

> ... 37 **non-wiki** questions ... 25 **non-wiki** answers ...

They say **non-wiki**, meaning it is not community wiki, so you had 2 community wiki posts that you posted, here is my link to your search:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4632019%20wiki%3ayes%20is%3aa

You have two wiki posts.